# geom_point() is appearing but geom_line() is not

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am running this renderPlotly code in R shiny but for some reason the geom_point is working with the tooltips but not the geom_line:

```
output$Bulk_Weight_Plot <- renderPlotly({

  p <- ggplot(truck_chart_df(), aes(x = Forecast_Date, y = Bulk_Weight)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("Forecast Date") +
    ylab("Bulk Weight") +
    scale_color_ptol("cyl") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
  p <- ggplotly(p)
  p

})
```

This is what it looks like in the app

[image]

Below is a snippet of the example data

[image]

Any advice or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: One possible issue might be that your `Forecast_Date` is a `character` instead of a proper date. To fix that you could try with explicitly setting the `group` aes, i.e. do `ggplot(..., aes(..., group = 1))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working app code and a snippet of your data or some fake data.